# How to use Facebook ID's to share data within app?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I am trying to use the Facebook id's to be able to share data within my app.

1. Simple plan: get the user Facebook ID (my ID). This is successful, I get the TestUser ID which matches the test user ID in the dashboard.
2. Then, I get the users friends and their ID's allowing the user to select the friends from a custom tableview.  The Facebook graph query however, for fields: id, it returns unique app based ID's.  Meaning they do not match the test users friends id's in the dashboard.

The problem, my app posts an image to the cloud with an array of the users selected friends ID's.  Meaning the unique app based id's are posted.  So when i go to a friends account and try to pull off all posts from the cloud that contain that users id, i am using the users id from 1 above.  Since this doesn't match the unique generated id from the friends list I can not query the data.

Any thoughts on how to overcome me getting my Facebookid but only getting my friends app unique Facebook ids?  Is it possible to get my app unique Facebook ID?  If so, then I would post to the cloud with it, so when my friends get my id, it matches.

**UPDATE 1 CODE**

This gets my friend ID's which as app scope id's.. the return ID is something like 80 characters long and does not match the user ID of the test users on the developer dashboard.

```
func returnFriends() {
    var request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"/me/taggable_friends", parameters: ["fields":"user_id,first_name,last_name,name,picture.type(large)"]);
    request.startWithCompletionHandler ({ (connection : FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result : AnyObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            print("Friends are : \(result)")
                    let jsonResult = result
                    self.friendsArray = jsonResult["data"] as! NSArray
                    var index = 0
                    for data in self.friendsArray {
                        let fn = data["first_name"]! as! String
                        let ln = data["last_name"]! as! String
                        let id = data["id"]! as! String
                        let picture = data["picture"] as! NSDictionary
                        let parsePic = picture["data"] as! NSDictionary
                        let url = parsePic["url"] as! String
                        self.friendProfile .updateValue((fn + " " + ln), forKey: id)
                        self.friendProfilePic .updateValue(url, forKey: id)
                        self.friendProfileID .updateValue(id, forKey: index)
                        index++
                        }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
        print("Error Getting Friends \(error)");
        }
    })
}
```

Then the below is to get my ID, which ends up being the user ID and matches my test user on the develop dashboard about 15 numbers long.

```
func returnUserData() {
    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/user_id", parameters: ["fields":"id,age_range,first_name,last_name,gender,name,picture.type(large)"])
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if ((error) != nil) {
            // Process error
            print("Error: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("fetched user: \(result)")
            let fn = result.valueForKey("first_name") as! String
            let ln = result.valueForKey("last_name") as! String
            let name = "\(fn) \(ln)"
            self.usernameLabel.text = name
            guard let id: String = result.valueForKey("id") as? String else { print("ID is null")
                return }
            print("ID is: \(id)")
            self.returnUserProfileImage(id)
            self.defaults.setObject(name, forKey: self.fbNameKey)
            self.defaults.setObject(id, forKey: self.fbIDKey)
        }
    })
}
```

**UPDATE 2 Results of Code**

This is my test user login returned info:  The ID matches the Facebook developer test user ID in the dashboard.

```
fetched user: {
    "age_range" =     {
        min = 21;
    };
    "first_name" = Mike;
    gender = male;
    id = 109240712780413;
    "last_name" = Alisonsky;
    name = "Mike Alajhcdecfgba Alisonsky";
    picture =     {
        data =         {
            "is_silhouette" = 1;
            url = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/s200x200/10354686_10150004552801856_220367501106153455_n.jpg?oh=2b8a15c932ebadfbd54c4576559bc9a6&oe=570FF350";
        };
    };
}
ID is: 109240712780413
```

And this if from when I return friends.

```
Friends are : {
    data =     (
                {
            "first_name" = Joe;
            id = "AaKcjMZP1bX72NUURIgWYoZxoV_5yy9NX3WWpfWlUBEXRtoSOSNBOER_43DfxLKQhIDUPhilv67FGCAgjOQlh13NdpqA1o6hSH2_u-7pEM71gg";
            "last_name" = Warmanson;
            name = "Joe Alajgejijfdab Warmanson";
            picture =             {
                data =                 {
                    "is_silhouette" = 1;
                    url = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/s200x200/10354686_10150004552801856_220367501106153455_n.jpg?oh=2b8a15c932ebadfbd54c4576559bc9a6&oe=570FF350";
                };
            };
        },
```

The ID here does not match the test user that I have for this friend in the Facebook developer dashboard.

Edit 2 Why

I want a user to be able to chose a Facebook friend to send a photo too. So I was thinking, post the photo to cloudkit, with the friends Id that I get with the above code.(friend id would be the abdhAbfhd style one) Then I want that friend to query cloudkit to pull down that photo. The only way I can think to do that is by using the friends id. But in order for that friend to have the id to pull down they need the same one I posted to the cloud with. Which I am assuming is app scoped. With the above. The Id I get when I ask for my user id, to query the database for my photos is the 100... one. I would need one that my friend posted which would be similar to the aabdcktishf....

Comment: Can you provide some code to show what you've tried?

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? why do you want to post the IDs of users? what for? do you actually want to TAG users?

Comment: @luschn updated answer on why above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All, after discussion on the Facebook developer forum it was found that toggle friends though returning all my friends it was not returning their id's but rather returning a tag. Which can change so not good as an identifier. What I need to query is me/friends vs taggable-friends. Friends will return my friends that have authorized my app and therefore return the scope id's of those users.

So the id I was getting from when I queried me is my scope Id which I can use to query, and when I get the friends id's they should match the id's used in the Facebook dashboard.

So it was my misunderstanding of using taggable-friends vs just friends.